# How do I play Pandora with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pandora

I get this error:

[image]

> Please ensure you are using the latest Flash Player.
>   If you are unable or do not wish to upgrade your Flash Player,
>   please try a different browser.
>   Please check our Help page for information about troubleshooting Pandora on your browser.

https://www.pandora.com/

Version 55.0.2883.87 m

From chrome://plugins

```
Adobe Flash Player - Version: 24.0.0.186
Shockwave Flash 24.0 r0
Name:   Shockwave Flash
Description:    Shockwave Flash 24.0 r0
Version:    24.0.0.186
Location:   C:\windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer32_24_0_0_186.dll
Type:   PPAPI (out-of-process)
    Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash 
.swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash Player 
.spl
```

Comment: What version of flash are you using? Is flash activated? You can find it at chrome://plugins

Comment: Yes it's activated.

Comment: Have you tried following this guide: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en

Comment: None of those 3 error messages occur. Chrome only uses it's own Flash.

Comment: It's working now. Must have been a bug on Pandora.

Answer (score 1):

Install User-Agent Switcher for Chrome from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US , and switch the User Agent to IE 10.  That Extension isn't in the regular Extension store for some reason, but it appears to be legitimately from Google .  Several people at my work had Pandora report "Please ensure that you are using the latest Flash version" in various browsers, and none of the suggested fixes worked.  Pandora worked fine in Edge, but no one wanted to use that.  The Agent Switcher bridged the gap, but may cause problems for sites that expect IE 10 computers to actually be IE 10.